# jQuery - hide <tr> by clicking on link in <td>

Tags: jquery

I currently have a table that looks something like this...

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

When clicking on the remove link, I would like to hide that current . This is the following code I've tried, but with no luck.

```
$(".remove").click(function() {

  $(this).parent("tr").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function of jquery to see the closest up the hierarchy. Parent will look just one level.

```
$(".remove").click(function() {

  $(this).closest("tr").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method will only look at the immediate parent. You need to go up one level further, with the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$(this).closest("tr").hide();
```

You could alternatively (just to give you an idea of what's going on) call `.parent()` twice:

```
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
```

The selector you pass to `.parent()` is used to return the parent element *if* it matches, rather than return the first ancestor that *does* match - notice that I've not passed anything to `.parent()` in the example above, which works just fine.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/sCkVR/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest()` instead of `parent()`:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrgzZ/)**